# Is there a geometrical meaning to inequalities about norms of orthogonal transformations?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, orthogonality

Let $V$ be a normed vector space of a finite dimension $n$.
We say that a linear map is orthogonal if $\| Av \| = \| v \|$ for every $v \in V$.
The norm of a liner map is defined as $\|A\|=max_{v\in V,\|v\|=1}\|Av\|$.

I also denote $O(V)$ as the set of all orthogonal maps over $V$.

I saw the following inequality:

Let $f \in O(V)$, such that $\|f-I\|\leq\vert\frac{1}{r}\vert$ for some $0 \neq r \in \mathbb{Z}$, then:
$$\|f-I\|\leq\|f^{r}-I\|$$

I want to know if there is some geometrical meaning to this inequality (preferably with a drawing).

I know that $\|A\|=1$ for every orthogonal map $A$, so $O(V)$ is the unit in the space of all linear maps. I also remember that there is something about orthogonal maps that is connected to the angle, but I'm not sure.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $r$ an integer?

Comment: @Arthur Yes it is! thank for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometrical meaning, as I see it, is as follows: $O(V)$ consists of rotations and reflections. And $\|f-I\|$ measures how far $f$ moves any unit vector. Setting this to be smaller than $\frac1{|r|}$ means that $f$ doesn't move any vectors very far.

If you have a vector $v$ and apply $f$ to it many times, then eventually $f^kv$ may end up close to $v$ again. The main intuition behind the inequality $\|f-I\|\leq\|f^{r}-I\|$ is that $r$ times isn't enough; $f^rv$ is necessarily still further away from $v$ than $fv$ is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you elaborate on why does $f^k v$ will end up close to $v$ again? and why is $f^rv$ is still further away?

Comment: @GabiG I am just intuiting about how rotations work in 2 and 3 dimensions. And if $f$ is a small rotation there, we eventually, as we apply $f$ many times, come around for a full revolution (not necessarily exactly one full revolution, but close enough). I am pretty certain that the same happens in higher dimensions too. But $r$ applications of $f$ is too few. In 2 or 3 dimensions, $r=2$ means we rotate by at most $29^\circ$. And rotating that twice isn't anywhere near enough to go around the circle.

Comment: Thank you, it's clearer now.